# How to get all child elements in the parent element of xml in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

think this is my xml ..

```
<ListOfDestinations>
  <Destination>
    <City>Ahmedabad</City>
    <Title>Cheap Flights to Ahmedabad</Title>
    <Content>
    <Top10PlacestoVisit>
      <subTitle>1</subTitle>
      <details>d1</details>
      <subTitle>2</subTitle>
      <details>d2</details>
      <subTitle>3</subTitle>
      <details>d3</details>
      <subTitle>4</subTitle>
      <details>d4</details>
      <subTitle>5</subTitle>
      <details>d5</details>
      <subTitle>6</subTitle>
      <details>d6</details>
      <subTitle>7</subTitle>
      <details>d7</details>
      <subTitle>8</subTitle>
      <details>d8</details>
      <subTitle>9</subTitle>
      <details>d9</details>
      <subTitle>10</subTitle>
      <details>d10</details>
    </Top10PlacestoVisit>
    </Content>
   </Destination>
 </ListOfDestinations>
```

so I want to get all `subTitle` and `details` to a list.how can I do that.This is what I tried.

```
XmlDocument DestinationXml = new XmlDocument();
DestinationXml.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Xml_Data/Destination.xml"));
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(DestinationXml.InnerXml);


var selectedCity = xdoc.Descendants("ListOfDestinations")
                        .Select(d => d.Elements("Destination")
                        .Where(w => w.Element("City").Value == DesName));
```

**in this place get all the data(subTitle and details) inside the  `<Top10PlacestoVisit></Top10PlacestoVisit>`**

then I created a `Model` and assigned values like this.but I can't get `subTitle` and `details` at once to the list.this is what I tried

```
foreach (var itemz in selectedCity)
{
    var needed = itemz.Elements("Top10PlacestoVisit");
    foreach (var nitems in needed)
   {
       var getSubs = needed.Elements("details");
       foreach (var itm in getSubs)
       {
           details.Add(new Destinations
          {
               details = itm.Value
         });
       }
  }
}

ViewBag.details = details;
```

in here it successfully gets `subTitle` but how can I get `details` and assign it in the same time.help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck with your XML, then you can do it by assuming the structure using something like this:

```
var topPlacesForCity = doc.Descendants("Destination")
    .Where(x => (string) x.Element("City") == "Ahmedabad")
    .Descendants("Top10PlacestoVisit")
    .Elements("subTitle")
    .Select(subTitle => new
    {
        SubTitle = subTitle.Value,
        Details = (string) subTitle.ElementsAfterSelf("details").First()
    });
```

If, as you mention in the comments, you can change this to incorporate a parent `Place` element, then it's a little more robust and obvious:

```
var topPlacesForCity = doc.Descendants("Destination")
    .Where(x => (string) x.Element("City") == "Ahmedabad")
    .Descendants("Top10PlacestoVisit")
    .Elements("Place")
    .Select(place => new
    {
        SubTitle = (string) place.Element("subTitle"),
        Details = (string) place.Element("details")
    });
```

As an aside, there is no reason to load your XML into `XmlDocument` to then just parse it straight into `XDocument` and throw it away.  Use `XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("..."))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your xml looks not quite good structured. From my point of view it would be reasonable to put `subTitle` and `details` related to it into some enclosing parent element something like:

```
<Top10PlacestoVisit>
    <Place>
      <subTitle>1</subTitle>
      <details>d1</details>
    </Place>
```

Anyway, if you're tied up with the structure you've posted and can't change it - you are still able to achieve your goal something like:

```
var details = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(
       string.Format("/ListOfDestinations/Destination[City='{0}']/Content/Top10PlacestoVisit/details", DesName))
    .Select(d => new { subTitle = (d.PreviousNode as XElement).Value, details = d.Value})
    .ToList();
```

Notice here using of `XPathSelectElements` in such a manner to get collection of `details` is my personal preference, you can do it anyway you like. Key idea here is:

```
.Select(d => new { subTitle = (d.PreviousNode as XElement).Value, details = d.Value})
```

on the collection of `details` elements. So you're just accessing previous sibling element  using `PreviousNode` property of `XElement` and for each `details` element it is exactly its related `subTitle`.

Comment: what is this `XPathSelectElements` it didn't work for me

Comment: It is extension method located in `System.Xml.XPath`. Make sure you have references `System.Xml.Linq` assembly and using this namespace in your code.

Comment: @bill think I have added `<place></place>` as a parent.then ho can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this, add your `subTitle` as a `Attribute` inside the `details` tag like this

```
<Top10PlacestoVisit>

  <details subTitle ="place01">d1</details>

</Top10PlacestoVisit>
```

then call it like this.

```
XElement xe = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("your path"));

            var check = xe.Descendants("Destination")
                        .Where(n => n.Element("City").Value == "Ahmedabad")
                        .Select(l => l.Element("Top10PlacestoVisit"));

            List<someList> dst = new List<someList>();
          foreach (var item in check)
          {
              var subs = item.Elements("details");
              foreach(var item1 in subs)
              {
                  dst.Add(new someList 
                  {
                      detail = item1.Value,
                      subtitle = item1.Attribute("subTitle").Value

                  });
              }
          }

          ViewBag.all = dst;
```